# Display file png,jpg,... JSP with Spring MVC 3

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm working on a Spring MVC 3 web application, I have some JSPs that works well with an exception, I'm having some problem displaying images -gif, jpeg and so on-. I tried these on the JSP side:

```
<img alt="TestDisplay" src="../images/XXX.gif" />
<img src="<c:url value=""/>images/XXX.gif" alt="TestDisplay"/>
<img src="<c:url value="/"/>images/XXX.gif" alt="TestDisplay"/>
<img src="<c:url value="../images/XXX.gif"/>" alt="TestDisplay"/>
<img src="<c:url value="/"/>WEB-INF/images/XXX.gif" alt="TestDisplay"/>
<img src="<c:url value="../WEB-INF/images/XXX.gif"/>" alt="TestDisplay"/>
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/XXX.gif" alt="TestDisplay" />
<img src="images/XXX.gif" alt="TestDisplay"/>
<img src="<spring:url value="/images/XXX.gif" htmlEscape="true" />" align="right"     alt="TestDisplay"/>
```

But I'm not sure if the real problem comes from pages or anywhere. Any helpful answer will be rated.

Application Hierarchy Tree:

/webapp

//images

+XXX.gif

//WEB-INF

///images

+XXX.gif

Yes, I know images folder is duplicated, I've done it just to try any of the above options.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you expand on the error you're getting, or are they just not showing up?  If you try accessing the URL of the image explicitly, does it just give a 404 or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shawn D. When I try accessing the URL I get a 404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct usage is:

```
<img src="<c:url value="/images/XXX.gif" />" alt="TestDisplay"/>
```

Files in `WEB-INF` are not accessible to clients.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already tried this one and it does not work.

Comment: I didn't see it in the list above. Are you sure it is precisely looking that way? Btw, can you open the image from the URL?

Comment: well, then the image is not accessible. Perhaps you should use mvc:resources

Answer (score 1):

you need to add to your applicationContext.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/*" location="/images/" />
```

to tell Dispatcher Servlet that you will use resources from this location

or

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

to use conteiner's default servlet for static resources handling.

more info about it - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-default-servlet-handler

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify your code like below. This should work fine.

### In xxx-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.asset" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Add images or CSS folder inside resources
e.g WebContent/resources/images/logo.png

Access the image using this statement

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/resources/images/logo.png"></a>
```